# Customizing the template within a Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that is using markup from Bootstrap, like the following:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Legend text</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="nameInput">Name</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="nameInput">
        <p class="help-block">Supporting help text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

There's a lot of boilerplate code in there, that I'd like to reduce to a new directive - form-input, like follows:

```
<form-input label="Name" form-id="nameInput"></form-input>
```

generates:

```
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="nameInput">Name</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="nameInput">
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have this much working via a simple template.

```
angular.module('formComponents', [])
    .directive('formInput', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                label: 'bind',
                formId: 'bind'
            },
            template:   '<div class="control-group">' +
                            '<label class="control-label" for="{{formId}}">{{label}}</label>' +
                            '<div class="controls">' +
                                '<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="{{formId}}" name="{{formId}}">' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>'

        }
    })
```

However it's when I come to add in more advanced functionality that I'm getting stuck.

### How can I support default values in the template?

I'd like to expose the "type" parameter as an optional attribute on my directive, eg:

```
<form-input label="Password" form-id="password" type="password"/></form-input>
<form-input label="Email address" form-id="emailAddress" type="email" /></form-input>
```

However, if nothing is specified, I'd like to default to `"text"`.  How can I support this?

### How can I customize the template based on the presence / absence of attributes?

I'd also like to be able to support the "required" attribute, if it's present.
Eg:

```
<form-input label="Email address" form-id="emailAddress" type="email" required/></form-input>
```

If `required` is present in the directive, I'd like to add it to the generated `<input />` in the output, and ignore it otherwise.  I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I suspect these requirements may have moved beyond a simple template, and have to start using the pre-compile phases, but I'm at a loss where to start.

Comment: Am I the only one seeing the elephant in the room :) --> What if `type` is set dynamically via binding eg. `type="{{ $ctrl.myForm.myField.type}}"` ? I checked all methods below and could not find any solution which will work in this scenario.  Looks like template function will see **literal values**  of the attributes eg. `tAttr['type'] == '{{ $ctrl.myForm.myField.type }}'` instead of `tAttr['type'] == 'password'`. I am puzzled.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

```
angular.module('formComponents', [])
  .directive('formInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            var type = attrs.type || 'text';
            var required = attrs.hasOwnProperty('required') ? "required='required'" : "";
            var htmlText = '<div class="control-group">' +
                '<label class="control-label" for="' + attrs.formId + '">' + attrs.label + '</label>' +
                    '<div class="controls">' +
                    '<input type="' + type + '" class="input-xlarge" id="' + attrs.formId + '" name="' + attrs.formId + '" ' + required + '>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            element.replaceWith(htmlText);
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: This is a little late, but if in `htmlText` you added an `ng-click` somewhere, would the only modification be to replace `element.replaceWith(htmlText)` with `element.replaceWith($compile(htmlText))`?

Comment: @Misko, you mentioned to get rid of scope. Why? I've a directive which does not compile when used with isolated scope.

Comment: this does not work if `htmlText` contains an ng-transclude directive

Comment: Unfortunately I've found that form validation doesn't seem to work with this, `$error` flags on the inserted input never get set.  I had to do this within a directive's link property: `$compile(htmlText)(scope,function(_el){ element.replaceWith(_el); });` in order for the form's controller to recognize its newly formed existence and include it in validation.  I could not get it to work in a directive's compile property.

Comment: how to bind ng-model template's input?

Comment: Okay, it's 2015 out there and I'm pretty sure there's something awfully wrong in generating markup in scripts **manually**.

Comment: This is a perfect example for a directive with a template function (instead of compile function). Or under Angular 1.5+ a component with a template function.

Comment: Nice answer. This can also be used in a `link` function.

Answer (score 38):

Tried to use the solution proposed by Misko, but in my situation, some attributes, which needed to be merged into my template html, were themselves directives.

Unfortunately, not all of the directives referenced by the resulting template did work correctly. I did not have enough time to dive into angular code and find out the root cause, but found a workaround, which could potentially be helpful.

The solution was to move the code, which creates the template html, from compile to a template function. Example based on code from above:

```
    angular.module('formComponents', [])
  .directive('formInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function(element, attrs) {
           var type = attrs.type || 'text';
            var required = attrs.hasOwnProperty('required') ? "required='required'" : "";
            var htmlText = '<div class="control-group">' +
                '<label class="control-label" for="' + attrs.formId + '">' + attrs.label + '</label>' +
                    '<div class="controls">' +
                    '<input type="' + type + '" class="input-xlarge" id="' + attrs.formId + '" name="' + attrs.formId + '" ' + required + '>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';
             return htmlText;
        }
        compile: function(element, attrs)
        {
           //do whatever else is necessary
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This solved my problem with an embedded ng-click in the template

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too. Wanted to wrap a directive to apply some default attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't even aware that the template accepted a function!

Comment: This is not a workaround. It is the right answer to the OP. Conditionally crafting a template depending on the attributes of the element is the exact purpose of a directive/component template function. You should not use compile for that. The Angular team is heavily encouraging this style of coding (not using the compile function).

Comment: This should be the correct answer,even i was not aware template takes a function :)

Answer (score 5):

The above answers unfortunately don't quite work. In particular, the compile stage does not have access to scope, so you can't customize the field based on dynamic attributes. Using the linking stage seems to offer the most flexibility (in terms of asynchronously creating dom, etc.) The below approach addresses that:

```
<!-- Usage: -->
<form>
  <form-field ng-model="formModel[field.attr]" field="field" ng-repeat="field in fields">
</form>
```

```
// directive
angular.module('app')
.directive('formField', function($compile, $parse) {
  return { 
    restrict: 'E', 
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var fieldGetter = $parse(attrs.field);

      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var template, field, id;
        field = fieldGetter(scope);
        template = '..your dom structure here...'
        element.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I've created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/joesavona/6985935) with more complete code and a [writeup](http://justandsimply.com/blog/2013/10/14/dynamic-forms-in-angularjs/) of the approach.

Comment: nice approach. unfortunately when using with ngTransclude i get the following error: `Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found.`

Comment: and why not use an isolated scope with 'field: "="'?

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Unfortunately your written approach is offline :(

Comment: Both the gist and writeup are dead links.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I ended up using.

I'm very new to AngularJS, so would love to see better / alternative solutions.

```
angular.module('formComponents', [])
    .directive('formInput', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attrs)
            {
                var type = attrs.type || 'text';
                var required = attrs.hasOwnProperty('required') ? "required='required'" : "";
                var htmlText = '<div class="control-group">' +
                    '<label class="control-label" for="' + attrs.formId + '">' + attrs.label + '</label>' +
                        '<div class="controls">' +
                        '<input type="' + type + '" class="input-xlarge" id="' + attrs.formId + '" name="' + attrs.formId + '" ' + required + '>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                element.html(htmlText);
            }
        }
    })
```

Example usage:

```
<form-input label="Application Name" form-id="appName" required/></form-input>
<form-input type="email" label="Email address" form-id="emailAddress" required/></form-input>
<form-input type="password" label="Password" form-id="password" /></form-input>
```

Comment: A better solution is to: (1) use a compile function instead of linking function and do the replacement there. The template will not work in your case since you want to customize it. (2) get rid of scope:

Comment: @MiskoHevery Thanks for the feedback - would you mind explaining why a compile function is favoured to a link function here?

Comment: I think this is the answer, from http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive : "Any operation which can be shared among the instance of directives [e.g., transforming the template DOM] should be moved to the compile function for performance reasons."

Comment: @Marty Are you still able to bind one of your custom inputs to a model? (ie. `<form-input ng-model="appName" label="Application Name" form-id="appName" required/></form-input>`)

Comment: @JonathanWilson using the ng-model attribute should work as expected, e.g. `<form-input label="Name" form-id="nameInput" ng-model="value"></form-input>` and `<input ... + 'ng-model="' + attrs.ngModel + ...` in the htmlText variable of the compile function.

Comment: @MartyPitt From O'Reilly's "AngularJS" book: "So we've got the `compile` phase, which deals with transforming the template, and the `link` phase, which deals with modifying the data in the view. Along these lines, the primary difference between the `compile` and `link` functions in directives is that `compile` functions deal with transforming the template itself, and `link` functions deal with making a dynamic connection between model and view. It is in this second phase that scopes are attached to the compiled `link` functions, and the directive becomes _live_ through data binding"