# Set templateUrl base on attribute in directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm working on a set of angular directives and I want to load the correct template based on the presence or value of an attribute.

```html
<my-form horizontal> </my-form>
<my-form vertical> </my-form>
```

If horizontal, templateUrl should be `/partials/horizontal-form` and
If vertical,   templateUrl should be `/partials/vertical-form`

I'm interested in the templateUrl because I can't use `template` since the html depends on the attributes. In the `compile.pre` function, the html has already been loaded.

If there is another way of achieving this, I'm open to it since I'm now starting with angular and the more info the better.

Thanks

Comment: I've looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629238/angularjs-customizing-the-template-within-a-directive). It is a similar idea except that this one is based on <code>template</code> so everything is inline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular.js directive dynamic templateURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl)

Comment: in AngularJS 1.5, you can use this solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743424/1274852

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the solutions for this is to use an ng-include inside the template file.

The first attribute inside of the template file will have something like :

```
<div ng-include = "getTemplate()">

</div>
```

In your directive code you would write something like :

```
scope : {direction : "="},
link : function(scope,element,attrs)
{
    scope.getTemplate = function(){
        if(scope.direction === "horizontal")
        {
            return "horizontal.html";
        }
        return "vertical.html";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed, one solution will be to use ngInclude. Will try it to solve the problem while looking for another way around it. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone searching, here is a cleaner way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23999356/656963

Answer (score 22):

fyi this is now properly fixed in angular 1.1.4

you can pass a function to templateUrl.   input parameters are element, attributes.   and returns a string (the templateUrl you wish to use)

docs here: http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/guide/directive

Comment: updated link [http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/partials/guide/directive.html](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/partials/guide/directive.html)

Comment: Although @jaysun pointed the proper way to do it (a function to set templateUrl value) in some scenarios (e.g. sub-rendering within the template already loaded, the approach pointed by ganaraj may be practical too)

Comment: I don't think it compiles the attributes though... like you can't pass this hoping template attr compiles to 'RADIO' for example (but you could literally put template="RADIO" and it would work, but obviously not useable for dynamic questions in my example): 

<div ng-repeat="subquestion in currentquestion.subquestions">
 <question question="subquestion" template="{{subquestion.question_type}}" />
</div>