# How to include function with parameter inside ng-include directive in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, controller

I am trying to include function inside ng-include directive. The function takes in parameter and based on this loads dynamic content.

I am using the following syntax to achieve this functionality but is not working.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-include src="'getCategoryDetail(cat_id)'"></div>
<div>{{results}}</div>
</div>
```

And here is my controller

```
  myapp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getCategoryDetail=function(catid)
        {
            $scope.catid=catid;
            $http.post('categoryDetail.php',{catId:scope.catid}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.results=data;
            })
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is not working because you are performing an asynchronous call inside of the getCategoryDetail function.  Additionally, you are assigning the result of the POST to a 'results' scope variable, but you aren't using it anywhere inside the include.

This post might answer your issue.
[Angular.js directive dynamic templateURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl)

Comment: Yes, the asynchronous call is being made inside the function to return result for each specific category id. Also, since the scope variable is a global variable, it should be accessible anywhere within the controller and the 'results' scope variable is binded inside this controller.

Comment: Right, but your getCategoryDetail function doesn't return anything, so your ng-include has src="''"

Comment: That is my question. How do i make this function return something? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: @meheshu Try using defer `$q` using which you can return from the function.

Comment: Is the data being returned HTML?  If you can change your POST to a GET, then I think you could do `<div ng-include src="categoryDetail.php?cat_id={{scope.catid}}"></div>`

Comment: @CodeHater Can you guide me on this? How do i make use of deferred implementation specific to my needs. If you could show me with some example, it would be great.

Comment: @AndrewH The data being returned is in JSON. What i want is keeping models and views separate. Anyway, i will check with your solution and see if it fulfills my requirement.

Comment: If the data is JSON, then I don't think you need the ng-include at all (especially since ng-include wants HTML).  You can just have {{}} bindings directly to the values inside of your data. Since you assigned the data to your results scope variable, you could have something like {{results.dataItem1}} in your HTML markup because Angular will automatically convert the JSON to javascript objects.

Comment: @AndrewH But i need a way to pass my variable(category ids) to the Controller from the template.

Comment: Where does cat_id come from?  Are you going to have more than one div with different catids?

Comment: Exactly, there will be more than one div with different cat_ids. The cat_ids come from another controller which returns an array of catids. I loop through the array using ng-repeat. <div  ng-repeat="item in categoryresults"><div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-include src="'getCategoryDetail(item.cat_id)'"></div>
<div>{{results}}</div>
</div></div>

Answer (score 0):

I think a custom directive could help out a lot.

In your main controller:

```
myapp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.categoryIds = ids //I don't know where these come from, but that's up to you.
});
```

Then you can define a directive, let's call it category

```
myapp.directive('category', ['$http', function ($http) {
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    template : '<div>{{results.dataItem1}}</div>', //You could define your template in an external file if it is complex (use templateUrl instead to provide a URL to an HTML file)
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        category: '@',
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$http',
        function($scope, $element, $attrs, $http) { 
            $http.post('categoryDetail.php', {catId:$scope.category}).success(function(data) {
                $scope.results = data;
            });
        }]
    };
}])
```

Now we can use our directive. In your main HTML page:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="catId in categoryIds" category="catId"></div>
</div>
```

this will render one div for each category id and each will load its own data.   Hopefully this helps.  I haven't tested this, so it may need some tweaks.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This should definitely help. I will check it out and do some tweaking if need be as per my requiremnt.

Comment: Great.  Please accept my answer if it works for you.