# Angularjs custom directive passing object data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to build a custom directive where I can pass an object and depending on that object render a different HTML.

Let's say that the object look's like this.

```
$scope.obj = {
  type: 'input',
  placeholder: 'Some text…',
  name: 'first_name'
}
```

The custom directive should look like this (I guess)

```
<renderObj data="obj" />
```

This should render a input field with the given data. I guess I have to use either the `link` or `compile` method within the directive, but how? Notice that the `obj` could have many different types of data and would be more complex than this simple example. So I must be able to decide within the directive what to render with which data.

Maybe I don't need a custom directive at all and use `ng-include` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js directive dynamic templateURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl)

Comment: There are lots of ways to include display logic within directives. Try something and when it isn't working as expected post that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$compile` to build out dynamic DOM. Code within the directive would look like this:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
  // ...
  if (data.type === 'input') {
    $compile('<input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}} name="{{name}}"></input>')(scope.data, function (clonedElement) {
      element.append(clonedElement);
    });
  }
  // ...
```

Generally though I would suggest trying to do as much of this in your directive template as possible. Imagine a template for the directive like:

```
<div>
  <input ng-if="data.type == 'input'" type="text" placeholder="{{data.placeholder}}" name="{{data.name}}" />
</div>
```