# AngularJS - dynamically load templateURL when passing object into attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angular-template

In my controller HTML I am passing an object into a directive as such:

```
<div cr-count-summary countdata="vm.currentCountData"></div>
```

The `vm.currentCountData` is an object that is returned from a factory

My directive code is below:

```
function countSummary() {
    var directive = {
        scope: {        
            countData: '='
        },
        link: link,
        templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.countdata.type === 'Deposit') {
                return 'app/count/countsummary/countDeposit.html';
            } else {
                return 'app/count/countsummary/countRegisterSafe.html';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that `vm.currentCountData` is a valid object with a `.type` property on it. However, it doesn't recognize it. I have tried simplifying things by just passing in `countdata="Deposit"` in the controller HTML. I've also changed  `attrs.countdata.type` to just `attrs.countdata` and it does evaluate as the string.

When I have it set up as I have shown above the directive `templateUrl` function seems to evaluate prior to the controller

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl), but it seems to only be evaluating strings

What do I need to do in order to allow attrs recognize the object?

Comment: use count-data="..." to refer on scope as countData:"="... on scope, camel case will find by hyphen separated attribute of html tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in this way, because at the time of evaluating `templateUrl` function angular doesn't have any scope variable, scope gets created after the compile function of directive generates `preLink` & `postLink`.

I'd prefer you to use `ng-include` directive inside the directive template, and then on basis of condition do load the desired template in it.

**Markup**

```
<div cr-count-summary count-data="vm.currentCountData"></div>
```

**Directive**

```
function countSummary() {
    var directive = {
        scope: {        
            countData: '='
        },
        link: link,
        template: "<div ng-include=\"countdata.type === 'Deposit' ? "+
                     "'app/count/countsummary/countDeposit.html' :" + 
                    "'app/count/countsummary/countRegisterSafe.html'\">"+
                  "</div>"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was having a hard time figuring out why templateURL was being evaluated prior to the controller

Comment: With not having access to scope, is there anyway to make this into a function? It's possible that there might be different templates to load