# Function in directive is running a lot more than expected

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am attempting to set the template of a directive dynamically using tips from this [link](https://medium.com/angularjs-meetup-south-london/angular-directives-using-a-dynamic-template-c3fb16d03c6d#.a6mirw9z2)

Here is the code for my directive.

```
var app = angular.module('sck-table', [

]).directive('tableInput', function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            field:'=field',
        },
        template:'<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>',
        controller: function($scope){
        $scope.count = 0;
            $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
               $scope.count++;
                console.log('this has been ran: '+$scope.count);
                console.log($scope.field.type);
                if($scope.field.type === 'select'){
                    return 'table/views/table-input-select.html';
                }
                if($scope.field.type === 'number'){
                    return 'table/views/table-input-number.html';
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I am using this directive inside of an ng-repeat directive that runs 2 times.(test.fields has a length of 2)

```
<td ng-repeat="field in test.fields">
    <table-input field="field" ></table-input>
</td>
```

I expect the function getTemplateUrl() to run twice.  Once for each item in test.fields.

However when I run this... the console logs 28 times.[image]

I seem to get the desired results... meaning the template is successfully injected into the page, but I was wondering if anyone could tell me why the getTemplateUrl() function is called so many times, and if I can do anything to prevent this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how many rows do you have in your table?

Comment: only one row... just testing for now

Comment: Function calls in templates are evaluated on each digest cycle.

Comment: Phil is correct. To avoid this, you should assign the result of getTemplateUrl() to a $scope model property inside of your controller constructor, then bind to the model property in your template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular.js directive dynamic templateURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl) but look to the [most upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23999356/283366) instead of the accepted one

Comment: Can't you just call a function instead of having `ng-include` and a function call. You can use your `field` attribute or smth like that for each of the directive. Doesn't look pretty anyway((

Comment: Yeah, take a look at the link @Phil provided

Comment: The most upvoted answer requires passing in the url through the attributes.  This is not what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments left on my question and the linked posts,  I have come up with this solution.

```
var app = angular.module('sck-table', [

]).directive('tableInput', function(){
    var contentUrl;
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            field:'=field',
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            scope.contentUrl = 'table/views/table-input-'+scope.field.type+'.html';
        },
        template: '<ng-include src="contentUrl"/>'
    };
});
```