# replaceWith not working for div ng-include

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have a div having replace-with custom directive.

```
 <div class="timeline" layout="row" ng-repeat="event in ::vm.events">
     <div replace-with='{{event.content}}'></div>
</div>
```

This is my directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('replaceWith', replaceWith);

    /* @ngInject */
    function replaceWith() {
        // Usage:
        //
        // Creates:
        //
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('replaceWith', function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    element.replaceWith(angular.isUndefined(value) ? '' : value);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

My Controller from where i am getting content data:

```
 vm.templateUrl = "scripts/controllers/sample.content.html";
 vm.events = [{
            title: 'Title1',
            subtitle: '',
            date: '6/6/2016',
            image: 'assets/avatar-5.png',
            content: '<div ng-include="vm.templateUrl"></div>',
            palette: ''
        }]
```

Here my div with replace-with attribute is not getting replaced with ng-include template.but when i hard code my content data like `content:<p>Sample Data</p>` it's working. can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Try `(document).ready(function(){}` instead of `(function()`

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist:i did not get you. which function you are talking about.

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need a directive for this? couldn't you simply use ng-include in the HTML template?

Comment: I'm not very good with jQuery but i thought it starts out with `(document).ready(function()` instead of `(function()`

Comment: @LarryTurtis:Well i have  lot of events on  vm.events and each event contains different html or image.so i want one custom directive to replace content.

Comment: take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the templateURL property of the directive and make it dynamic, as described in the top answer to this question:

[Angular.js directive dynamic templateURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl)

Comment: i appreciate your help . will try above solution.