# Dynamically changing Angular directive based on attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I want to change the template/templateUrl whenever a specific attribute changes. I currently have the following, which does load the initial image correctly, but doesn't change on update.

```
.directive('parkingImage', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            image: '='
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.contentUrl = 'img/parking/'+attrs.templateUrl+'.svg';
            attrs.$observe("template-url", function(v){
                scope.contentUrl = 'img/parking/'+v+'.svg';
            });
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>'
    }
}]);
```

and in html `<parking-image id="parking-image" template-url="Area_2"></parking-image>`

I took a look at this [Angular.js directive dynamic templateURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl) , but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to observe on `templateUrl` rather than `template-url`:

```
attrs.$observe("templateUrl", function(v){
    scope.contentUrl = 'img/parking/'+v+'.svg';
});
```

Comment: It now updates on the initial page load, but not yet whenever it changes