# AngularJS directive templateUrl function using 2-way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to parameterize the template of a page using a directive.
I have an array of objects with a 'type' value. I want to use different templates when types are different.

Here is what I tried:

**directive.js**

```
angular.module('core')
  .directive('mySolutionDisplay', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        solution: '='
      },
      templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
        return 'path/to/template/solution-'+attr.type+'.template.html';
      }
    };
  });
```

**view.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <my-solution-display type="vm.solution[0].type" solution="vm.solution"></my-solution-display>
</div>
```

I get the following error : 
`angular.js:11706 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: path/to/template/solution-vm.solution[0].type.template.html`

I tried replacing `type="vm.solution[0].type"` by `type="{{vm.solution[0].type}}"` but it just added the curly brackets to the error message.

Comment: <div class="row">
  <my-solution-display type="{{vm.solution[0].type}}" solution="vm.solution"></my-solution-display>
</div>

Comment: Have you tried like that, i think at type="" it does not resolve the variable name and you can try adding the curly braces there

Answer (score 0):

Attributes (attrs) has no access to scope variable. They get the dom value after they have been interpolated.

So, use

`<my-solution-display type="{{vm.solution[0].type}}" solution="vm.solution">
</my-solution-display>`

Note how `type="vm.solution[0].type"` was changed to `type="{{vm.solution[0].type}}"`

Comment: I already tried this but it just adds the curly brackets in the error description.
`angular.js:11706 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: path/to/template/solution-{{vm.solution[0].type}}.template.html`

Comment: Yeah, ignore my answer. Looks like that's just not possible. See the bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13526.

Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl for another way of solving this problem.