# Is there a way to dynamically render different templates for an angular 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have a number of angular 1.5 components that all take the same attributes and data structure. I think they could be re-factored into a single component, but I need a way to dynamically choose a template based upon the interpolated value of the `type` attribute.

```
var myComponentDef = {
    bindings: {
        type: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: // This should be dynamic based on interpolated type value
};

angular.module('myModule').component('myComponent', myComponentDef);
```

I can't use the `templateUrl function($element, $attrs) {}` because the values in the `$attrs` are uninterpolated so I wouldn't get the type specified in the passed in data.

I could just have one big template with a series of `ng-if` or `ng-switch` directives, but I would like to keep the templates separate.

Alternatively, I could just keep the components separate and use `ng-switch` etc in the parent component, but I don't like this as it seems like a lot of repetition.

I'm looking for a solution where I can use the interpolated `type` passed into the bindings to match a template url for each type which will then be used to build the component.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible since it requires the `$compile` service which is not available to components. You can use directive though.

Comment: see this simple and elegant solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743424/1274852

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not something that components were specially made for. The task narrows down to using a directive with dynamic templates. The existing one is `ng-include`.

To use it within a component, it should be:

```
var myComponentDef = {
  bindings: {
    type: '<'
  },
  template: '<div ng-include="$ctrl.templateUrl">',
  controller: function () {
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => {
      if (changes.type && this.type) {
        this.templateUrl = this.type + '.html';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really like this. I injected an angular constant into the controller which contains all of the config mapping types to particular urls, so the line can be `this.templateUrl = typeMapperConfig[this.type];`

Answer (score 12):

You can inject any service and set dynamic url

```html
angular.module('myApp').component("dynamicTempate", {
        controller: yourController,
        templateUrl: ['$routeParams', function (routeParams) {
           
            return 'app/' + routeParams["yourParam"] + ".html";
        
        }],
        bindings: {
        },
        require: {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Much better solution than calling ng-include.

Comment: not if you need an item passed in to determine what the url should be

Comment: you can inject any service and get the url from it and return that url

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the switching logic somewhere in any case so why not simply have it in a parent component template?

Having clean and understandable AngularJS template in that case is IMO more valuable than a bit of repetition:

```
<ng-container ng-switch="$ctrl.myComponentDef.type">
  <component-type1 ng-switch-when="type1" param="$ctrl.myComponentDef"></component-type1>
  <component-type2 ng-switch-when="type2" param="$ctrl.myComponentDef"></component-type2>
</ng-container>
```

Even if you change the myComponentDef.type on the fly, the components in the switch will correctly call their respective `$onDestroy` and `$onInit` methods and load data as expected - no magic, no voodoo.