# Does angular 1.x have a generic feature or pattern?

Tags: angularjs

Currently I have a preview list component which displays a list of preview components from array data:

```
<preview-list previews="previewsArray"></preview-list>
```

The problem here is that I have to build a new list component for every page instead of just plugging in components and data. Is there a way to generalize the preview list component so that I can display arbitrary lists of components? In a manner similar to this:

```
<component-list list="previewsArray component="preview"></component-list>
```

Comment: I don't know about a generic, but a possible solution to this would be using [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch). You would have to create a new case every time you wanted to add a new possible component type to `component-list`, but it would be one line, and probably pretty easy to manage.

Comment: Another option is to add templates to the templateCache and `ng-include`, like demonstrated in [this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640326/498719)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may look like that : [Insert directive programmatically angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656735/insert-directive-programmatically-angular)

This is a hard way but I see nothing else.

Related doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#!

Optionnal doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector