# Setting different component template according to condition Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a component and I need to have two different templates depending on some condition. For example, I have a "testApp" component and if condition is true, the parent tag needs to be an anchor tag, otherwise parent tag has to be a div. The html content inside the parent container will be the same inside both templates.
I am trying to figure out a way to do this, but I cannot find how and where to write the condition to choose the template.

```html
angular.module('testApp').component('testCard', { 
templateUrl: 'testCard', // inlined template 
controller: [TestCardController]
});

<script type="text/ng-template" id="testCard">
  <div class="test-card">
    // same content 
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="testCard">
  <a class="test-card">
  // same content
 </a>
</script>
```

Comment: Why does the template itself need to be different? Why can't you have a wrapper and use `ng-if`?

Comment: Is this question about angular or angularjs? Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Can you please elaborate? I only started learning angular js recently....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to supply a function for templateUrl instead of a string.  See [More than one template in same component in AngularJS 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902174/more-than-one-template-in-same-component-in-angularjs-1-5)