# ng-repeat in combination with custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having an issue with using the ng-repeat directive in combination with my own custom directive.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <x-template-field x-ng-repeat="field in ['title', 'body']" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('templateField', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            compile: function(element, attrs, transcludeFn) {
                element.replaceWith('<input type="text" />');
            }
        };
    });
```

See [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDfxd/)

The problem here is that nothing is replaced. What I'm trying to accomplish is an output of 2x input fields, with the 'x-template-field' tags completely replaced in the DOM. My suspicion is that since ng-repeat is modifying the DOM at the same time, this won't work.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629238/angularjs-customizing-the-template-within-a-directive%20this) Stack Overflow question, the accepted answer seems to indicate this has actually worked in earlier versions of AngularJS (?).

#### Wouldn't element.html('...') work?

While element.html('...') actually injects the generated HTML into the target element, I do not want the HTML as a child element of the template tag, but rather replace it completely in the DOM.

#### Why don't I wrap my template tag with another tag that has the ng-repeat directive?

Basically, for the same reason as above, I don't want my generated HTML as a child element to the repeating tag. While it would probably work decently in my application, I would still feel like I've adapted my markup to fit Angular and not the other way around.

#### Why am I not using the 'template' property?

I haven't found any way to alter the HTML retrieved from the 'template' / 'templateUrl' properties. The HTML I want to inject is not static, it's dynamically generated from external data.

#### Am I too picky with my markup?

Probably. :-)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, and have been messing with it for a month with no good solutions.

Answer (score 16):

Your directive needs to run before `ng-repeat` by using a higher priority, so when `ng-repeat` clones the element it is able to pick your modifications.

The section "*Reasons behind the compile/link separation*" from [the Directives user guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) have an explanation on how ng-repeat works.

The [current `ng-repeat` priority](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L149) is 1000, so anything higher than this should do it.

So your code would be:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('templateField', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            priority: 1001, <-- PRIORITY
            compile: function(element, attrs, transcludeFn) {
                element.replaceWith('<input type="text" />');
            }
        };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your `ng-repeat` in the template. You could modify attributes of element and accordingly in directive to determine if ng-repeat is needed, or what data to use inside the directive compiling

HTML(attribute):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" template-field></div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('templateField', function () {
        return {          
            restrict: 'A',
            template:'<input type="text" value="{{field}" ng-repeat="field in [\'title\',\'body\']" />'            
        };
    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/GDfxd/3/

Also works as an element :

HTML(element):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
    <template-field/>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('templateField', function () {
        return {          
            restrict: 'E',
            replace:true,
            template:'<input type="text" value="{{field}}" ng-repeat="field in [\'title\',\'body\']" />'

        };
    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/GDfxd/3/

Comment: It is difficult for me to use the 'template' property, because the HTML I want to generate for each field could be a lot of things. It could be an input tag, a textarea tag, or something completely different (such as markup triggering *another* directive). This is why I want to use the 'compile' property to specify a function that can insert virtually anything into the DOM.