# isolate scope in directive undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble creating a directive, since the isolate scope does not get passed from the html and gives me undefined in the directives controller.

**lmLoop definition**

```
angular.module('loops.directives')

.directive('lmLoop', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: 'modules/loops/partials/loop.tpl.html',
     scope: {
       loop: "=",
     },
     controller: ['$scope', '$log',
       function($scope, $log) {
         console.log($scope.loop);   // undefined
       }
     ]
  }
});
```

**modules/loops/partials/loop.tpl.html**

```
<div class="loop-container">
  Testing: {{ loop.message }}  <!-- empty -->
</div>
```

How Im trying to **use** my directive

```
<div class="loops-container">
  <lm-loop ng-repeat="loop in loops" loop="loop"/>
</div>
```

This renders the view correctly, meaning that it repeats the right amount of times, once for each item in the array, but it does not pass the variable "loop" and the div stays empty. But when I do the following it *renders correctly* and *displays the message*

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="loop in loops">
    {{ loop.message }}  <!-- WORKS!!! -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

The ***directive*** and the ***ul*** are both inside another directive. That directive gets the *loops* by a service like this:

```
controller: function($scope) {

  loopService.getLoops($scope.group._id, function(loops) {
    $scope.loops = loops;
  }, function(err) {
    $log.error(err);
  });

  ... Other code ...

}
```

I don't know whether the asynchronous call to the service gets the data after the 
**lmLoop** directive gets instantiated and therefore makes the data undefined? Or maybe (probably) I'm doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `priority: 1001` in your directive

Good explanations here [ng-repeat in combination with custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344306/ng-repeat-in-combination-with-custom-directive)

Comment: I just have a problem now that `$scope` not working, do you have some tips for solving that issue as well?