# angularjs repeat custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i want to output custom directives from a custom directive in a ng-repeat for drag&drop purposes. my problem is that the myWidget outputs the html-tag correctly but the custom directive isn't executed.

similar to this post:
[ng-repeat in combination with custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344306/ng-repeat-in-combination-with-custom-directive)

main directive template:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 hidden-md main-column" style="height:inherit;"
         ng-model='list2'
         data-drop="true"
         data-jqyoui-options="{accept:'div:not([ng-model=list2])'}"
         jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">

        <div ng-repeat="item in list2"
             ng-model="list2"
             data-drag="{{item.drag}}"
             data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}"
             jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true}">
                <div my-widget="item.widget"></div>
        </div>
```

directive for dynamic call:

```
(function(){
"use strict";

angular
    .module('achilles')
    .directive('myWidget', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                w: '=myWidget'
            },
            restrict: 'EA',
            priority: 300,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.replaceWith('<' + scope.w + '>');
            }
        };
    });})();
```

the inspector shows that the output is  but the directive is not triggered.

```
(function(){
"use strict";

angular
    .module('achilles')
    .directive('anamnesisWidget', anamnesisWidget);
```

is there some kind of priority or scope problem that causes the 3. directive to not trigger?

Comment: output is: <anamnesis-widget></anamnesis-widget>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `compile` that directive element using `$compile` before replacing it, so that the underlying directive will get called and it will renders it element.

**Code**

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.replaceWith($compile('<' + scope.w + '/>')(scope));
}
```

Comment: i had to inject $compile and then it worked. why do i need (scope) after $compile?

Comment: @user2436745 I didn't mention the `$compile` part in your code..Its common thing in Angular do inject services before using them.. `$scope` tells angular that do convert(compile) the `element` in angular context which will have this `scope` available on it..