# Passing multiple values to a directive with ng-repeat inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive like this:

```
<user-preview closable="true" user="user" ng-repeat="user in users"></user-preview>
```

As you can see, I pass  two attributes to it: `closable` and `user`. With user everything is fine, it gets to the internal template of the directive. But closable doesn't. It exists inside internal scope, but in template it's `undefined` for some reason.
If I move ng-repeat to an external tag, it works:

```
<span ng-repeat="user in users"><user-preview closable="true" user="user"></user-preview></span>
```

So how do I pass both values with `ng-repeat` inside? Is it possible?

Here is code of my directive just in case:

```
.directive('userPreview', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            'user': '=',
            'closable': '='
        },
        restriction: 'E',
        replace: true,
        priority: 1001,
        templateUrl: '/static/angular_tpls/user_preview.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        }
    }
});


<span class="badge active user">
    <a href="#">
        <img ng-src="{{user.avatar}}" height="25px" class="img-circle">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        {{user.name}}
    </a>
    <span ng-if="closable" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" ng-click="close()"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344306/ng-repeat-in-combination-with-custom-directive

Comment: I already use higher priority.

Comment: see: http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/GDfxd/213/. I had such problem, but now...

Comment: Thank you! I removed priority and works now. What a weird behaviour.

Comment: don't use `'='` for isolated scope when it isn't a parent scope variable. That is for 2-way binding

Comment: @charlietfl. why? what do you suggest?. is it `=something`?

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev because `$scope.true` doesn't exist in parent controller

Answer (score 0):

this way you can easily pass your value.

```
 getUser();
 function getUser() {
   $scope.userList= ["user 1", "user 2", "user 3", "user 4", "user 5", "user 6"];
   $scope.Listobj= $scope.userList.map(function(user){
   return {
    userInfo: user,
    closable:true
   }
 });
}
```

your custom directive

```
<user-preview closable="user.closable" user="user.userInfo" ng-repeat="user in Listobj"></user-preview>
```