# directive one inside another is not working in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My case is one parent directive and many child directives .

Actually my requirement want to include one inside another directive. Like that we have to use many directive.

Can anyone help me to find out what is wrong on this code or provide any examples which is working like our requirement.

JS Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/Lcch85a1/

**Angular JS Directive Code**

```
bosAppModule.directive('layoutView',function($compile){
    var layoutObj={};

    linkFn=function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
        console.log("Layout : ");
        console.log(scope.layoutData);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        //var containerString = "<layoutContainerView layout-data='layoutObject.Data' container-data='containers' ng-repeat='containers in layoutData.collections.container.rowSet'>Hello container  {{containers.containerId}}   </layoutContainerView>";
        //var compiledElement = $compile(containerString)(scope);
        //element.append(compiledElement);
    };
    layoutObj.scope={layoutData:'='};
    //layoutObj.transclude='true';
    layoutObj.restrict='E';
    //layoutContainerObj.replace='true';
    layoutObj.template="<div id='{{layoutData.collections.layout.rowSet[0].layoutId}}' layout-data='layoutObject.Data'>Hello layout     {{layoutData.collections.layout.rowSet[0].layoutId}}</div>";
    layoutObj.link = linkFn;

    return layoutObj;   
});

bosAppModule.directive('containerView',function($compile){
    var layoutContainerObj={};

    linkFn=function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        console.log("Container : ");
        console.log(scope.layoutData);
        console.log(scope.containerData);
    };
    layoutContainerObj.scope={layoutData:'='};
    //layoutContainerObj.transclude='true';
    layoutContainerObj.restrict='E';
    //layoutContainerObj.replace='true';
    layoutContainerObj.template="<div >Hello container  {{containers.containerId}} </div>";
    layoutContainerObj.link = linkFn;

    return layoutContainerObj;  
});
```

**HTML Source Code:**

```
<layout-view layout-data='layoutObject.Data'>
    <container-view layout-data='layoutObject.Data' ng-repeat='containers in layoutObject.Data.collections.container.rowSet'></container-view>
</layout-view>
```

Comment: Please search for your problem before creating a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat in combination with custom directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344306/ng-repeat-in-combination-with-custom-directive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your JSFiddle - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/camden_kid/mjvt6td5/2/)

Markup

```
<layout-view>
</layout-view>
```

JS

```
layoutObj.template="<div>Hello layout <container-view ></container-view>  </div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344306/ng-repeat-in-combination-with-custom-directive). I think quite a few people have asked this question in less words, with a less complicated situation.

This is the answer from @rgarcia...

> Your directive needs to run before ng-repeat by using a higher
>   priority, so when ng-repeat clones the element it is able to pick your
>   modifications.
>
> The section "Reasons behind the compile/link separation" from the
>   Directives user guide have an explanation on how ng-repeat works.
>
> The current ng-repeat priority is 1000, so anything higher than this
>   should do it.

Try adding `priority: 1001` to your directives like this...

```
bosAppModule.directive('layoutView',function($compile){
    var layoutObj={};
    priority: 1001

    linkFn=function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
        console.log("Layout : ");
        console.log(scope.layoutData);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        //var containerString = "<layoutContainerView layout-data='layoutObject.Data' container-data='containers' ng-repeat='containers in layoutData.collections.container.rowSet'>Hello container  {{containers.containerId}}   </layoutContainerView>";
        //var compiledElement = $compile(containerString)(scope);
        //element.append(compiledElement);
    };
    layoutObj.scope={layoutData:'='};
    //layoutObj.transclude='true';
    layoutObj.restrict='E';
    //layoutContainerObj.replace='true';
    layoutObj.template="<div id='{{layoutData.collections.layout.rowSet[0].layoutId}}' layout-data='layoutObject.Data'>Hello layout     {{layoutData.collections.layout.rowSet[0].layoutId}}</div>";
    layoutObj.link = linkFn;

    return layoutObj;   
});
```

Additionally, you could further nest the directive. I believe this abstracts when and how many times Angular is looking to replace your custom HTML with the functionality you're looking for. I.E.

**Template .html Document**

```
<custom-tag ng-repeat="..."></custom-tag>
```

**Create This Directive:**

bosAppModule.directive('abstractedDirective',function(){
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "path/to/template/foo.html"
});

**Update Your HTML**

```
<layout-view layout-data='layoutObject.Data'>
    <abstracted-directive></abstracted-directive>
</layout-view>
```