# How to initialize an AngularJS directive model from child elements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to initialize some data in an AngularJS directive with child elements. In this case, the `<map>` element is replaced with a `<div>` that gets hooked up using leaflet.  I was trying to figure out if there is some way in the directive `compile` or `link` function to populate the `markers` collection from declared child elements, something like this:

```
<div ng-app="dashboard">
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
    <map id="devicemap" tile-handle="test.map-fy18v14h" min-zoom="3" max-zoom="9" markers="markers">
        <marker lat="44" lng="-88.5" description="From the Server (Razor)" />
        <marker lat="44.1" lng="-88.6" description="From the Server 2 (Razor)" />
    </map>
</div>
```

In the directive, I would like iterate over the `<marker>` elements to populate a collection.  Should this happen in compile?  Or, am I misguided that I can access my "fake DOM" prior to the actual template being inserted?

```
module.directive('map', function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        markers: "=markers"
    },
    template: '<div class="map"></div>',
    link: function link(scope, elm, attributes) {
        var map = L.map(attributes.id, {
            dragging: true,
            zoomAnimation: true
        }).setView([45.505, -88.09], 6);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/' + attributes.tileHandle + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: "<a href='http://mapbox.com/about/maps' target='_blank'>Terms & Feedback</a>",
        }).addTo(map);

        // This is where I am stuck... is there a way to get the "marker" elements?   
        // the following does not work...
        var markerElements = elm.children('marker');  

        // now would like to loop over markerElements, grab the attributes and add them 
        // to the map (and/or the markers collection).

    };
});
```

I am able to populate the markers using an ajax call, however, this technique would allow me to pre-populate the data on the server when the page is first requested.

Comment: Because you are using a `template` (and `replace: true`), by the time the link function runs, the `<marker>` tags have been removed.  That's why the link function can't find them.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there a way to access the original DOM before it gets replaced?

Comment: You can do that in the compile function, but you can't use `template` (or `replace: true`), otherwise the compile function will see the applied template rather than the original DOM.  Inside the compile function you can use `replaceWith()` when you're done modifying the DOM.  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10646761/215945

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the hint from Mark Rajcok, I have come up with a solution.  This allows me to set up the markers on the map using custom HTML elements that are generated on the server.  I needed to use the `list` variable to store off the data collected in the `compile` function.  Not sure if there is a cleaner way to do this with Angular.

**HTML/Razor**

```
<div ng-app="dashboard">
    <div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
        <map id="devicemap" tile-handle="example.map-fy18v14h" min-zoom="3" max-zoom="9" markers="markers">
        @foreach (var location in Model.Locations)
        {
           <marker lat="@location.Lat" lng="@location.Lng" description="@location.Description" ></marker>                                   
        }
        </map>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var module = angular.module('dashboard', ['map-directive']);
module.controller("DashboardCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.markers = [];
});
```

**Directive**

```
var mapDirective = angular.module("map-directive", []);

mapDirective.directive('map', function () {

    var list = [];

    function link (scope, elm, attributes) {
        var map = L.map(attributes.id, {
            dragging: true,
            zoomAnimation: true
        }).setView([45.505, -88.09], 6);

        scope.markers = list;

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/' + attributes.tileHandle + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: "<a href='http://mapbox.com/about/maps' target='_blank'>Terms & Feedback</a>",
        }).addTo(map);

        scope.$watch('markers', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue)
                angular.forEach(scope.markers, function (marker) {
                    L.marker([marker.lat, marker.lng], { draggable: marker.draggable }).addTo(map).bindPopup(marker.description);
                });
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            markers: "=markers"
        },

        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {

            console.log(tElement);
            console.log(tElement.find("marker"));

            var markers = tElement.find("marker");


            angular.forEach(markers, function (marker) {
                list.push({ lat: marker.attributes.lat.value, lng: marker.attributes.lng.value, description: marker.attributes.description.value});
            });

            var htmlText = '<div class="map" id="' + tAttrs.id + '" ></div>';
            tElement.replaceWith(htmlText);
            return link;
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: `list` will be shared by all `map` directives in the app.  If you plan on using more than one `map`, then you'll need to have multiple lists, or convert the `list` from an array to an object, where each property is the `map`'s id, and each property value is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use derective with templateUrl.
Just put ng-transclude on any element there and it will have all original children elements as its own.
Then in link function you can read those DOM elements, do whatever you ant and clean them up.