# how to map my "dynamic subview" to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I really like the concepts behind AngularJS and think i have a good understanding of the fundamentals to write a very basic CRUD application. But once I am trying to transfer the knowledge to a real-life problem, I am starting to struggle how it maps to the concepts in AngularJS.

My problem: I want to have a dynamic "subview" (visually a popup, modal, wizard; however you want to name it). that is controlled by a custom controller.

Speaking with some HTML I have something like this:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and I want to inject based on an event (button-click) a subview into this div. This template (which i could inject via ng-include for example) should by on its own independent of a controller; i want to bind those two pro grammatically, so i can reuse the template with different explicit controllers.

So, the first question: How do I do something like binding a controller to a sub-portion of the DOM (the div) pro grammatically?

And secondly, I want to also have generic and reusable controllers. E.g. create a controller with a a name for a custom headline text, but everything else is the same logic-wise. How do I pass these kind of parameters to a controller? As controllers are created implicitly via the AngularJS framework, there is really no hock for me to create a controller programmatically WITH a set of parameters. Or is there?

Sorry for this rather abstract explaination, and I don't expect you to give me a working solution, but I appreciate any help/comments that will guide me in the right direction.

In the end, i want to map something like this to AngularJS:

```
var ctrl = new PopupController("subviewtemplate.html", "headline text");
screenCtrl.show(ctrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're against creating a controller. Make it a directive. Or modify/look into an existing approach like Angular-UI's message directive.
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dialog

I'd suggest using ng-include as a function in a template to create a dynamic template approach like this:

[Customizing the template within a Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629238/angularjs-customizing-the-template-within-a-directive)

also useful:
["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1)