# AngularJS directive template with validation, ngModel and ngClass only works when template is wrapped

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using [Misko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10646761/202913) as a template, I've implemented a directive that provides a template for twitter bootstrap form controls.

This [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJucFDCk7tfcuDgunrqr?p=preview) has two directives which are identical except that the first directive has an additional div wrapper in the template.

Why is the 'has-error' class only being applied for the first directive and not the second one?
If I add the wrapping div to the second directive template it all of a sudden starts working. What is the significance of this wrapper?

I also see that the validation classes ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required etc. are applied correctly to the form element, but also the the top-level div in the directive template, why is that?

Answer (score 3):

At a guess as to what's the problem - Angular is adding validation classes to the first wrapping div it can. In the first one, this one is just an empty wrapper and the extra validation classes causes no problems. The second one already has both class and ng-class attributes in the first wrapper div, and Angular adding validation classes overwrites or conflicts with the ng-class rules causing them not to run and 'has-error' not to be applied. I'm not sure if there's a better solution than just keeping the wrapper div though.

Comment: Thanks Mikel, would really like to understand why this is happening though.