# AngularJS directives: How do I dynamically change the element html in an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that I'm applying an ng-repeat to. The purpose of the directive is to swap itself out with a different directive that is based on a value passed into the original directive:

`<content-type-directive type="item.type" ng-repeat="item in items"></content-type-directive>`

becomes

```
<type1-specific-directive></type1-specific-directive>
<type2-specific-directive></type2-specific-directive>
<type1-specific-directive></type1-specific-directive>
<type1-specific-directive></type1-specific-directive>
...
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/qPGZ8/6/

This would be straight forward to do if the html of the second directive could be rendered inside the first directive's wrapping element, but in this case I need it to actually replace the original item.

This is related to [Customizing the template within a Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629238/angularjs-customizing-the-template-within-a-directive)

In Misko's answer he explains using element.replaceWith() to swap out the original html. This works fine when the item is not in an ng-repeat, but inside of an ng-repeat it breaks the ability for the ng-repeat to update itself with new elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relating to the bug https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2151. Upgrading to the latest version `1.2.0` will fix it.

Btw, the button should be put in the controller's scope. Hope it was a typo.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ADGrm/)**</kbd>

Comment: It was indeed an oversight. Thanks for catching it. Using append doesn't work for me however because I need the original <article> element to be replaced by the new <div> element in the fiddle example.

Comment: @kyleder Updated. it is because a bug so you need to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks @sza. I [tried this out](http://plnkr.co/edit/jNEWZ5?p=preview) and it does work, though it leaves behind a copy of the original element (not a huge deal). Unfortunately, this is part of a fairly large project that will be hard to upgrade to 1.2 until the angular guys release a stable version.

Comment: @kyleder No Problem. Try 1.1.5. I can't recall when this issue got fixed. Good luck.

Comment: One thing to note about this solution is that the element that gets created is effectively appended to the parent which means that removing elements from the ng-repeat doesn't work. :/

Comment: @kyleder Oops! I forgot to change it back to `replaceWith`. Just updated the demo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37485/discussion-between-kyleder-and-sza)