# Dynamic template in AngularJS Directive (Not templatUrl)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have seen the ability to have a dynamic `templateUrl` within a Directive in Angular but while researching I have yet to see a dynamic template.

```javascript
.directive('col', function () {
    var template = '<div class="one" ng-transclude></div>';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: template,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            if (attrs.two !== undefined) {
                template = '<div class="two" ng-transclude></div>';
            } else if (attrs.three !== undefined) {
                template = '<div class="three" ng-transclude></div>';
            } else {
                template = '<div class="one" ng-transclude></div>';
            }
            console.log(template);
        }
    };
})
```

HTML:

```html
<col three>Three</col>
<col two>Two</col>
<col>Nothing</col>
```

The console shows appropriately:

> `<div class="three" ng-transclude></div>`
>   `<div class="two" ng-transclude></div>`
>   `<div class="one" ng-transclude></div>`

However the output shows the default / initial `<div class="one" ng-transclude></div>`

Comment: You probably want to be using the `compile` feature like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629238/angularjs-customizing-the-template-within-a-directive

Comment: @nuclearghost +1, this is good. Thanks. I will have to keep this in mind for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the template is collected before the `link` function is fired, if your only trying to change the classes then just do something like this.

```
.directive('col', function () {
    var template = '<div class="{{class}}" ng-transclude></div>';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: template,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            $scope.class = attrs.three ? 'three' : attrs.two ?'two' : attrs.one ? 'one' : '';
        }
    };
});
```

Other than that I don't know how else you would accomplish it.

Comment: With some minor tweaking this one worked perfectly, thanks. `$scope` was changed to `scope` and your ternary operator didn't work properly in my instance, but that could be on me.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'template = 'xxx' in your link function it is referencing your template variable, not the property on the returned object.  Try this:

```
.directive('col', function () {
    var result = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: template,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            if (attrs.two !== undefined) {
                result.template = '<div class="two" ng-transclude></div>';
            } else if (attrs.three !== undefined) {
                result.template = '<div class="three" ng-transclude></div>';
            } else {
                result.template = '<div class="one" ng-transclude></div>';
            }
            console.log(result.template);
        }
    };
    return result;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the template is dynamically constructed based on the attributes then you can just supply a template function passing in the attributes

```
.directive('col', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            var template = null;

            if (attrs.two !== undefined) {
                template = '<div class="two" ng-transclude></div>';
            } else if (attrs.three !== undefined) {
                template = '<div class="three" ng-transclude></div>';
            } else {
                template = '<div class="one" ng-transclude></div>';
            }

            return template;
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
})
```

If the template is dynamically constructed based on the model then it's bit more involved. Note that the transclusion is done explicitly rather than using the ng-transclude directive.

```
.directive('col', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myVariable: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, nullController, transclude) {
            var template = null;

            if (scope.myVariable == 'two') {
                template = '<div class="two"></div>';
            } else if (scope.myVariable == 'three') {
                template = '<div class="three"></div>';
            } else {
                template = '<div class="one"></div>';
            }

            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
                element.children().append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
})
```