# How can i conditionally add attribute in template in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Inside my directive template i have this

`<span sortable draggable></span>`

Now i want to conditionally add `sortable` and `draggale` based on some scope variable

When i try this

`<span ng-attr-sortable="false">`

It basically becomes

`<span sortable="false"></span>` which still makes it sortable

I want sortable to be completely removed if expression is false

`<span> </span>`

Comment: If you can base your decisions on the attrs of your directive rather than the scope variables, then this solution might work to dynamically build your template: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20659860/1454888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work with `elem.removeAttr('sortable')`. Where `elem` is the jQuery lite element, which you can pass in as `link: function (scope, elem) { ... }`, or using `elem.find(...)` to target a child element by tag name.

But that's something you may want to setup within your `link: function () {...}` as opposed to right in the template. You could always make your own filter for removing an attribute that you could then use within the template.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element (find `removeAttr`).

Comment: that removeAttr is not working. MY template conatins another directive . is that can be the case because i  have another dircetive inside that trmplate and i am trying to remove attribute from that directive

Comment: That works if i put inside compile function . If i put inside link function then it dont work. but in compile i don't have scope

Comment: @user3214546 Perhaps you need to recompile the element yourself and re-link it to the scope.

Comment: @demisx how can i do that , itried and it says compile function does not xist , any code??