# AngularJS Custom Directive replace HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

**home.html**

```
<videodata></videodata>
```

**videoctrl.js**

```
$rootScope.cameraRTSPUrl = obj.objUrl;
```

**directive.js**

```
directive - myApp.directive('videodata', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope : true ,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.replaceWith('<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" '+
                                    'codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" '+
                                    'id="vlc" events="True"> '+
                                    '<embed id="123" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" '+
                                    'loop="no" width="800" height="600" target="'+scope.cameraRTSPUrl+'"> '+
                                '</object>');

        }
    };
});
```

The above code works and rendered HTML is below

```
    <object events="True" id="vlc" 
        codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" 
        classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">
        <embed width="800" height="600" target="rtsp://localhost/media/media.amp" loop="no" autoplay="yes" 
        version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" id="123">
    </object>
```

1. The code works with `element.replaceWith` but is this the correct
   way to replace HTML using custom directive ?
2. How do I use `transclude: true,` property in order to replace my
   HTML ?

P.S. I am using `scope.cameraRTSPUrl` value inside `link` function.

Comment: Use `replace : true` and use `template : <your html>` in return object. That might help. Sorry, but I did not get what you want to achieve. In order to transcendent inner html of the directive, you also need to set `transclude:true` and use `ng-transclude` directive in your template. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: Downvoter pls explain. I am able to achieve the desired result but want to know the best way for the same.

Comment: Can you please tell me what results you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

> The code works with `element.replaceWith` but is this the correct way to replace HTML using custom directive ?

Nope. It is more or less the worst possible wrong way, because it prevents any Angular data or event binding or really any of the other reasons Angular is worth using; you're dumping a blob of uncompiled HTML into the page that Angular doesn't really know about.

You never want to modify the DOM directly in Angular.  If you *do* modify the DOM directly, what you add should almost always be `$compile`d first so Angular can find any data or event bindings inside it. (Experienced Angular devs may take issue with my use of the word "never".  It's true that there are some cases where this advice doesn't apply, but as a new-to-Angular developer you're unlikely to run into them for quite a while.  Best practice is to let Angular do the work until you have a good understanding of what it's doing. And then still let Angular do most of the work, because that's what it's good at.)

For your example, the way you've done it, the `ng-hide` wont work, and if the value of `scope.cameraRTSPUrl` changes, that change will not be reflected in the UI.  Instead, use a directive template or `templateUrl`, so you'll get access to Angular's data binding:

```
myApp.directive('videodata', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope : true,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/foo.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.cameraRTSPUrl = "someGeneratedValue.mov"; // could passed into the directive via an attribute or parent data binding, for example
        }
    };
});
```

foo.html:

```
<div ng-hide="StartPlay" id="streamingarea">
    <object events="True" id="vlc" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" 
        classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">
        <embed width="800" height="600" target="{{cameraRTSPUrl}}" loop="no" autoplay="yes" 
        version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" id="123">
    </object>   
</div>
```

Now you can trigger the `ng-hide` by just changing the truthiness of `scope.StartPlay`, and changes to `scope.cameraRTSPUrl` will appear in the DOM automatically.

> How do I use `transclude: true`, property in order to replace my HTML?

That's not really what `transclude` is for.  Transclude allows you to create directives that contain html not generated from within that directive (the part that comes from elsewhere is the "transcluded" bit; the transclude directive is a wrapper around that transcluded html.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and altering my code to above works and changes the target, but unfortunately my video does not play. This is was the issue initially and then I resorted to `replaceWith` method which plays video when target changes. How do I overcome this ?

Comment: Could be a few things.  How are you passing the target url to the directive?  (It's possible that the directive is being drawn with an empty target URL, the video 'autoplay' fails, then in the next digest you set `cameraRTSPUrl` -- if that's the case the easiest fix would probably be to trigger the video playback from within the link function rather than depending on autoplay.)   If that guess isn't right, this probably rates a new separate question...

Comment: User will drag the video link and place it on a div `streamingarea`. Before dragging the url, the generated html is `<div ng-hide="StartPlay" id="streamingarea" class="ng-hide">
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" id="vlc" events="True">
 <embed width="800" height="600" id="123" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" target="">
</object>
</div>`.

Comment: After directive usage and target is set, html set is, `<div ng-hide="StartPlay" id="streamingarea" class="">
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" id="vlc" events="True">
<embed width="800" height="600" id="123" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" target="rtsp://10.103.3.172/axis-media/media.amp">
</object>
</div>` How do I trigger video playback from within the link function rather than depending on autoplay ?

Comment: On further analysing, I found that replacing the whole `embed` html only  then video starts playing. Changing its target ot autoplay option does not have any impact and video does not load. how do I replace the whole html using your solution ? Ref - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629238/angularjs-customizing-the-template-within-a-directive

Comment: Yes, so that's exactly what I thought -- autoplay is trying to trigger before there is a target to play. You can either trigger it to play manually (using the video's .play() event) after setting the target url, or wrap it in an ng-if="cameraRTSPUrl" so it will wait to render until the target exists.

Comment: Tried using `ng-if` like this for embed element - `<embed ng-if="cameraRTSPUrl" width="800" height="600" target="{{cameraRTSPUrl}}" loop="no" autoplay="yes" 
        version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" id="123">`, and the embed object appears but does not play the video.

Comment: You may need to move the ng-if higher up the DOM tree so that the whole object node is drawn at the same time. Or trigger playback manually; that's probably preferable to depending on "autoplay" anyway...

Comment: Sir, I replace the whole object and also a div above it. Still it does not get the player to play the video. I am concerned that why `replaceWith` method (which is not advisable) works  while your solution (best in practice) does not ? What is that I am missing or any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Best way is to use template

template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'

 myApp.directive('videodata', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope : true ,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        template: '<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" '+
                                    'codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" '+
                                    'id="vlc" events="True"> '+
                                    '<embed id="123" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" '+
                                    'loop="no" width="800" height="600" target="'+scope.cameraRTSPUrl+'"> '+
                                '</object>'
        }
    };
});
```